# Get image URL inside Shadowbox onFinish?

Tags: php, jquery, shadowbox

How can I get the URL of the image currently being shown in Shadowbox for a function running in onFinish?  I'm trying to populate a div with EXIF information, and I can do that part with PHP, but I'm not sure how to do this per image in Shadowbox.

Thanks!

Comment: try `$(this).attr('src');` to get the src file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle Shadowbox Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vsrDm/)

To get the content of the currently displayed **Shadowbox** object, use the Shadowbox API `.getCurrent()` method followed by the `content` attribute:

**`Shadowbox.getCurrent().content`**

Then to use that in the Shadowbox `onFinish` hook option, here is the JavaScript method to use:

```js
onFinish: function(){

    document.getElementById('theLocation').innerHTML = 'File Location: ' + Shadowbox.getCurrent().content;

}
```

---

To populate your div using jQuery, it's always best to insure you are using Shadowbox with the Shadowbox jQuery Adapter interface (download option or CMS plugin option).

Reference: [**jsFiddle Shadowbox Demo with jQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/vsrDm/1/)

```
onFinish: function(){

    $('#theLocation').html('File Location: ' + Shadowbox.getCurrent().content);

}
```

---

**Status Update:**  [**jsFiddle HTML Markup Only**](http://jsfiddle.net/hvDGE/)

The above jsFiddle contains in the HTML panel all the markup you need (***less scripts mentioned***) to have a working example of showing **EXIF** data in a webpage div. It uses the jQuery .exif() plugin and has a lot of comments to understand and use with Shadowbox.

Comment: Hi Arttronics, thank you very much for this!  It's working great.  If I want to extend this a bit, however, and pass this along to an EXIF jQuery plugin, I figure I could do it like this, but it doesn't appear to be working.  Can you double-check my syntax?

`onFinish: function(){
$("#sb-body-inner").prepend("<div id='sb-exif'></div>");
$("#sb-exif").html("Taken with a: " + $(Shadowbox.getCurrent()).exif("Make") + " " + $(Shadowbox.getCurrent()).exif("Model")); }`

Comment: I now understand the entire scope of your Question. Simple errors in your markup include not using `.content` to get the file URL, using that Shadowbox API twice (hint: use variable), but more importantly your HTML will need to change to accommodate this feature since you need to include the added height of your dynamic div. Please provide link to `.exif()` plugin so I can provide correct jQuery and HTML for you ([***teaser jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/vsrDm/2/)). Cheers!

Comment: Art, the plugin can be found here: http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/jquery-exif-data-plugin.html  The functionality is more important than styling it, so far as I'm concerned, so I'm working on that first.  Thanks!

Comment: Art, thank you so much.  Your dedication to this is astounding.

Comment: NaOH, here is working markup to copy to your folder of using Shadowbox onFinish to provide EXIF information in a populated div. The example uses onFinish via a class name on the anchor you want to have this functionality. Reference: [**jsFiddle HTML Markup Only**](http://jsfiddle.net/hvDGE/)

Comment: Art, I will take a look at all of this today, and hopefully can implement it during the day here.  If I have any issues I will let you know, but you've already done way, way more than I could have ever expected so I don't really want to bug you either...

Comment: Feel free to bug me as much as you need to. I also created another unfinished method for Shadowbox showing EXIF as "**Shadowbox EXIF Captions**", but stopped since it's efficient to query (i.e., AJAX download is what `.exif()` does) each image after it's already on the webpage. To be sure, I know a lot about Shadowbox but don't visit that [**forum**](http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=320743) any longer.

Comment: I've done it, all thanks to you!  Have a look [here](http://www.element17.com) to see it in action.  I am still determining which fields I want to pull, and styling it and such, but that's trivial now. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: An outstanding Shadowbox website! I recommend removing Shadowbox `skipSetup` Option since when I first loaded the webpage and clicked on an image quickly, Shadowbox did not initialize that particular image "as-of-yet". Having said that, and due to the amount of images, the next time that happens will only render a non-functional Exif Button (until the page has completed loading).

Comment: Is there any way to speed up the functionality of the EXIF button?

Comment: Instead of using `Shadowbox.setup();` with that class name and applying the `onFinish` rule to those anchors, you can set it globally for anything Shadowbox opens by moving the `onFinish` (and `onClose`) into `Shadowbox.init({ });`, but this may impact other items that are not exif related since `Shadowbox.init();` is a global rule while `Shadowbox.setup();` targets the specific selector. Still, there is no guarantee (until it's tried) that accessing your website prior to load completion that Shadowbox is still busy caching objects. Maybe consider a Image Preloader script?

Comment: ... to be sure, a Image Preloader script will show "Loading" for the whole webpage until all images are properly displayed and cached by Shadowbox, but it might be overkill if it's not a big problem.

Comment: I'm interested in implementing a "Lazy Loading" plugin that will load only the images that are currently on the page, though all the ones I've found only work for <img> objects, not for <div>s with background images.  Is this sort of thing easy enough to implement from scratch?

Comment: I've never used either a Image Preloader or a the type of loading scheme you've mentioned (but known what you mean). If you go the Lazy Loading route (if/when with div support), then that must be a AJAX process which will require you to run `Shadowbox.setup();` for the newly added content. Having said that, it would seem to create more "mini-delays" than a single "big-one" that you currently have so I don't really see that as a worthwild solution.